# ComboBox not autoselecting initial value

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, combobox

I have a `ComboBox` bound to a list of people in a simple `ViewModel`. The SelectedPerson is set in the constructor of the ViewModel, but when I run the application, the ComboBox is not set with its initial value. What am I doing wrong?

Notice that two instances of the `MyPerson` class should be considered equal when they have the same Id.

Unfortunately, I cannot modify the `MyPerson` to override Equals (it's third party).

The only option I've seen so far is to user the Adapter pattern to wrap the instances of this class and implement a custom Equals method there.

I feel that **there should be a better method that is native to WPF to match items** from a list by some kind of "key". In my case, the list of items and the selected item come from different sources, and that's why they have an Id property acting as a primary key.

I've played with SelectedValue and SelectedValuePath, but nothing works.

```
<Window x:Class="Test.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:Test"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        x:Name="Root"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <vm:MainViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>
    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding People}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPerson}" SelectedValuePath="Id"
              DisplayMemberPath="Name"
              SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedPerson}" />
</Window>
```

And this ViewModel as DataContext:

```
public class MainViewModel
{
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        SelectedPerson = new MyPerson { Name = "Mary", Id = 1 };
    }

    public MyPerson SelectedPerson { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<MyPerson> People { get; } = new List<MyPerson>()
    {
        new MyPerson() {Name = "Mary", Id = 1 },
        new MyPerson() {Name = "John", Id = 2 },
    };
}

public class MyPerson
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: 1) First of all use `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface for your MainViewModel.
2) Add `OnPropertyChange` (or whaterver you will call it) to `selectedPerson` setter

Comment: 1) First of all use `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface for your MainViewModel.
2) Add `OnPropertyChange` (or whaterver you will call it) to `selectedPerson` setter
3) You use `SelectedValue` in a wrong way -> [Article] (http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/671544/Understanding-SelectedValue-SelectedValuePath-Sele)
4) Better use `SelectedItemIndex` to check what item is selected. Atm you supply `SelectedPerson` and `People` list with different objects with name Mary and Id= 1, that might bring some problems aswell.
* Couldn't  edit due to 5mins limit )) *

Comment: @Shakra In this case, I don't need to implement the interface. The value should be queried without change notification the first time the combo is loaded.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the new object you create here

```
SelectedPerson = new MyPerson { Name = "Mary", Id = 1 };
```

isnt' the same as in your list so the `Equals` method would return `False` in all cases!

As someone else already suggested, you have to get the real object that is in the list by doing this:

```
public MainViewModel(){
   SelectedPerson = People.First(x=> x.Name.Equals("Mary")); //Or: x.Id == 1
}
```

But there is also another solution: You can override the `Equals` function in your `MyPerson` class, so that every `MyPerson` instance with the same `Name` and/or `Id` would indeed be seen as the same person.

**EDIT**

As you're using ViewModels in your project, it would be better if you had a ViewModel for the `MyPerson`class too. It would solve your problems *and* make your design better!

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to say that MyClass is a third party class that I cannot modify. I modified the question.

Comment: You can still use the first solution to get the desired result. WPF doesn't know that an object is the same if the property values are. It's easier if you use MVVM. Your ViewModel would be (like you said in your answer) a kind of wrapper for your real object.

Comment: It would be better if you had a ViewModel for your MyPerson object anyway!

Comment: Exactly *why* would creating a ViewModel just for binding the ComboBox to a collection of objects benefit or solve any problems? You'd just be abstracting the `MyPerson` object to a ViewModel unnecessarily in this instance - *unless* you're then displaying/editing the some details of the person further down the line in the view.

Comment: As he said, MyPerson is a third party class and also a model. It would solve his problem because he could override the Equals method. Also, it would be a cleaner solution if he's using MVVM. Otherwise he's binding to a list of models and that's not the way to go in MVVM.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
public MainViewModel()
{
    SelectedPerson = new MyPerson { Name = "Mary", Id = 1 };
}
```

To

```
 public MainViewModel()
 {
     SelectedPerson = People.ElementAt(0);
 }
```

Or if ou want by name:

```
 public MainViewModel()
 {
     SelectedPerson = People.First(x=> x.Name=="Mary");
 }
```